# Mean field approximation

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian, variational-analysis

I am a Japanese student studying machine learning and stuff like that. When I have studied Mean Field Approximation [**HERE**](http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/variational-bayes-and-the-mean-field-approximation/), I got question.

In that post, equation (14) is as follows:
$$
L[q_1,...,q_m] - \sum_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_j\int_{z_j}q_j(z_j)dz_j = 0 $$

But I think it should be like:
$$
L[q_1,...,q_m] - \sum_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_j\left[\int_{z_j}q_j(z_j)dz_j - 1 \right] 
$$
Because we construct the Lagrangian with careful the following constraint:
$$
\int_{z_j}q_j(z_j)dz_j = 1 ~~~~~\textrm{for all }j
$$
It means that each $q_j$ is probabilistic density function.

Please help me.

Comment: I would agree with you for the reasons you give. The mistake doesn't cause a problem in what follows because all of the additive constants end up getting absorbed in to the normalizing constant anyway

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I could not understand what you said, so could you please explain it in another way? It means that I could not understand your English.

Comment: I mean that a) I agree with your Lagrangian. b) If you replace their equation (14) with your result and carry out the optimisation you will get the same result as in line number 2 of equation (16)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much Mr.Nadiels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you're right. If you want to construct the Lagrangian such that you can recover the constraints by setting the derivatives with respect to the Lagrangian multipliers to zero, you need to do it the way you say. However, since the constraints are already known, there's usually no need to recover them from the Lagrangian, and the Lagrangian is usually only used to derive the equations of motion by differentiating with respect to the $q_i$ (and $\dot q_i$). Since a constant in a constraint doesn't make a difference in the derivatives with respect to $q_i$, constants in constraints are often dropped in the Lagrangian for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I could not understand what this mean:「However, since the constraints are already known, there's usually no need to recover them from the Lagrangian, and the Lagrangian is usually only used to derive the equations of motion by differentiating with respect to the $q_i$ (and dot$q_i$ )」Could you pleas explain it in detail?

Comment: @JapaneseStudent: What I mean is: The Lagrangian contains all the information about the system in the sense that we can derive both the equations of motion and the constraints from it: the equations of motion by differentiating with respect to $q_i$ and $\dot q_i$, the constraints by differentiating with respect to the Lagrangian multipliers $\lambda_j$. If you want the Lagrangian to have this nice property, then you need to set it up as you did.

Comment: However, practically speaking, we never actually use the Lagrangian to re-derive the constraints, since we already know the constraints, we don't need to derive them by differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to the $\lambda_j$. So, practically speaking, if you only want to use the Lagrangian to derive the equations of motion by differentiating with respect to $q_i$ and $\dot q_i$, then you don't need to care about constants in the constraints, because they drop out when you differentiate with respect to $q_i$ and $\dot q_i$.

Comment: That’s make sense. Thank you Mr. joriki